# View coordinator on application startup: should I use View Controller or something else?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently my Main Interface for the app looks like this:

[image]

*Root View Controller* has no value on its own, it's needed to decide which controller to display. The logic is fairly complicated, but that's not important for this question. Simplest similar example would look like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        var controller: UIViewController?

        if !userIsAuthenticated {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
            controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginController")

        }
        else if systemHasAlert {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Alert", bundle: nil)
            controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "alertController")
        }
        else {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Landing", bundle: nil)
            controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "defaultLandingPage")
        }

        guard let _controller = controller else {
            return 
        }

        navigationController?.pushViewController(_controller, animated: true )
}
```

(the logic itself is symbolic, not *that* simple. But this is enough to convey the idea.)

This controller also provides a stable "return point" for when application state changes. For example after user successfully logged in, all I need to do is:

```
AppDelegate.shared.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```

which causes the conditions in *Root View Controller* to be reevaluated and application navigates to another view

Generally this works ok, but I dislike 3 things:

1. This Root view becomes visible for a moment, which sort of breaks smooth transitioning from one view to another. I tried to resolve it by replacing `viewDidAppear` with `viewWillAppear`, but in that case seems navigation is not happening at all
2. This view is technically not needed
3. On conceptual level it seems not right that view controller serves as a coordinator for other views.

So are there any better options to provide such "root level" coordinator? Or is root view coordinator the right choice, and I should rather worry about properly stylizing it, and not eliminating it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but it seems that you don't need the root view controller at all but you need to show one of the three controllers (i.e. "Login", "Alert" and "Landing") when application starts.

In this case it really seems that `viewDidAppear` method in view controller is not the best place to handle this logic. The easiest way is to handle your logic inside your `AppDelegate` class in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method. Your implementation may look like this:

```
var window: UIWindow?

...

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Initialize navigation controller without root view controller
    let navigationVC = UINavigationController()


    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    // Set navigationVC as a root view controller in your application
    // Now it would ignore your storyboard.
    window?.rootViewController = navigationVC

    var controller: UIViewController?

    if !userIsAuthenticated {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
        controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginController")

    }
    else if systemHasAlert {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Alert", bundle: nil)
        controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "alertController")
    }
    else {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Landing", bundle: nil)
        controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "defaultLandingPage")
    }

    if let controller = controller {
        navigationVC.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)
    }

    return true
}
```

**P.S.:** Keep in mind that implementation above overwrites the entry point for your application defined in storyboard file.

**P.P.S:** You mentioned "coordinators" in your original post. The way shown above is the easiest one but probably not the best one. For more complicated logic you may really need to implement coordinators. Although the coordinator concept is familiar to many iOS developers there is no single approach in implementation in iOS community. So I will just put several links discussing coordinators which I hope you will find useful:

1. http://khanlou.com/2015/10/coordinators-redux/
2. http://khanlou.com/2017/05/back-buttons-and-coordinators/
3. http://merowing.info/2016/01/improve-your-ios-architecture-with-flowcontrollers/
4. https://hackernoon.com/coordinators-routers-and-back-buttons-c58b021b32a
5. https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E5-connecting-view-controllers

Comment: Yes, the idea of coordinator is floating around... even my implementation is a variation of one such tutorial. 
Unfortunately I cannot use your suggestion for a few reasons. Two important ones are: firstly, I also want to reuse the same logic when application state changes, asI explained in example with logged in user. The other important reason is mentioned in the first link you provided: "Overstuffed App Delegates" is what I would like to avoid. 
But thanks for your response nevertheless!

Comment: You may put the logic defined in `AppDelegate` inside the `AppCoordinator` which will handle other coordinators (i.e. "LoginCoordinator", "LandingCoordinator", etc) and will also track application state changes. However you will need to initialize `AppCordinator` and I don't think there is a better place other than AppDelegate. You may probably consider this situation as "Overstuffed App Delegate" but I think in this case the logic inside `AppDelegate` would be pretty minimum.